# Creating a variable inside angular template and assign data from API in template itself

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-observables

I have a product table with 20 rows. I have to display the product image on each row which I should get from another service. The limitation is the image API takes only one product id at a time to return the image URL. So I have to make 20 API calls to get 20 images.

I am trying to do using the reactive approach and trying to subscribe to the API in the template itself as below

```
      <div  let-product-data="getProductImage(1234)| async" >
        
          <img  src="{{product-data.image}}">

      </div>
```

TS Code :

```
      getProductImage(imageId) {
         const url = `${environment.DEV}/product/stockroomInfo`;
         return this.http.post(url, {id:imageId});
      }
```

But the above code is not working. Can someone help me with what I am making wrong here?

Or this won't work this way? should I go for some other approach. Suggestions, please

Comment: What is the behavior? Is the API call even getting executed? Are you getting errors or is nothing happening?

Comment: Why are you doing a POST to retrieve an image? You have no advantage on this and you waste the ability of the browser caching the request. Also what do you mean by not working? You don’t retrieve the image or the image doesn’t show?

Comment: The API call is not happening. Also, I need to send few other key-value pairs in the payload and for that reason, the API developers made it a POST request. Just for simplicity, I have removed them here

Answer (score 0):

Your approach with using the async pipe inside *ngFor should work fine, however, it looks like your syntax is not quite right.

Instead of `let-product-data`, try something like this:

```
  <li *ngFor="let product of products$ | async">
    {{ product.name }}
    <img [src]="getProductImage(product.id) | async">
  </li>
```

Here's a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66068156?file=src/app/app.component.html)